# Get all sub-categories of a parent category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, list

How could I get a list of sub-categories (empty included) of a specific parent category (not within a post) by providing the parent category ID or slug? I need 3 levels depth.
Example: [picture](http://prntscr.com/rduh46)

My code so far:

```
function smart_category_top_parent_id ($catid) {
    while ($catid) {
       $cat = get_category($catid); // get the object for the catid
       $catid = $cat->category_parent; // assign parent ID (if exists) to $catid
      // the while loop will continue whilst there is a $catid
      // when there is no longer a parent $catid will be NULL so we can assign our $catParent
       $catParent = $cat->cat_ID;
    }
return $catParent;

$page_id = get_queried_object_id();

$category = get_the_category($page_id);

$catid = $category[0]->cat_ID;

$top_level_cat = smart_category_top_parent_id ($catid);

$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

$terms = wp_list_categories( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'style'    => 'none',
    'echo'     => false,
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'include'  => $top_level_cat,
    'show_count' => 1,
    'child_of' => 0,
    'separator' => '<br />',
    'style' => 'list',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'include' => $post_terms
   ) );

   return $terms;
```

Code above displays only the top parent category but not children.

Comment: Have you tried [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)?

Comment: Yeap, I have, after reading the documentation but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @SallyCJ added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your updated code, you should know that the `$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms()` would only return categories that *directly* attached to the post, so I'd just use [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) to get and display the child categories for the *given* (or a known) parent category.

And here's the code that works well for me which displays up to three levels of child categories including those having no posts. This code would replace the lines starting from the `$page_id = get_queried_object_id();` to the `$terms = wp_list_categories();` as in the question, and I'm using [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) instead of (your) `smart_category_top_parent_id()`:

```php
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();

$category = get_the_category( $page_id );
$catid = ( ! empty( $category ) ) ? $category[0]->cat_ID : 0;

if ( $catid ) {
    // Get all parent IDs.
    $parents = get_ancestors( $catid, 'category', 'taxonomy' );

    $top_level_cat = ( count( $parents ) > 1 ) ?
        $parents[ count( $parents ) - 2 ] : // use the second parent category ID, or
        array_pop( $parents );              // otherwise, we'll use the first one

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li'   => '',
        'echo'       => false,
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'child_of'   => $top_level_cat,
        'style'      => 'list',
        'hide_empty' => 0, // include empty categories
        'depth'      => 3, // and up to 3 levels depth
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I do not get the desired results. I get partial results.

Comment: I added code to the answer. Is that how you attempted it?

Comment: Yeap, I think it does, at least it seems so, I will verify later and mark the answer as correct. I think it worked before, but maybe lagged, I see you just removed some bits, am I right?

Comment: Yeap it does work, however could you please tell me how to replace $top_level_cat (which is the top parent) with his first direct child (to which the post belongs to)? Thank you.

Comment: Edited my code, works fine with yours, my previous question still exists for the first child of the top parent category.

Comment: I've revised the answer and added an updated code. Please try that and let me know. :)

Comment: You are great, works like a charm! Thank you so much!